# Could Not load plugin in self hosted server

Tags: java, minecraft

So I have grave plugin, but it says that it can't find the main class GravePlugin, although the main class is GravePlugin.
(I made this plugin.)

Here is the error

```
[23:24:37 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/graves.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `GravePlugin'
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:73) ~[paper-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:153) ~[paper-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:411) ~[paper-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:319) ~[paper-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:423) ~[paper-1.19.2.jar:git-Paper-307]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:278) ~[paper-1.19.2.jar:git-Paper-307]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1100) ~[paper-1.19.2.jar:git-Paper-307]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:305) ~[paper-1.19.2.jar:git-Paper-307]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GravePlugin
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:177) ~[paper-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:124) ~[paper-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:71) ~[paper-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
```

I wanted the grave plugin to create a grave when i died, but instead when i launched my self-hosted server, it said that it couldn't find the main class.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. is it your plugin?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is my plugin

,Elikill58

Comment: Could you provide your plugin.yml file and your GravePlugin code?